# How do i show a list of object in Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm still learning Django, using Class based view, i have created a ProductDetailView and have a ProductListView.
Everything  working perfect, but i want to add on my product_detail page, a list of products, after client viewed a product_detail page may also be interested by related product or what they may want. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj4NQ.png)

```
**my model.py**

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    featured = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    available_colours = models.ManyToManyField(ColourVariation, blank=True)
    available_sizes = models.ManyToManyField(SizeVariation)
    primary_category = models.ForeignKey(
          Category, related_name='primary_products', blank=True, null=True, 
          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondary_categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

ProductListView:

class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'cart/product_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    category = self.request.GET.get('category', None)
    if category:
        qs = qs.filter(Q(primary_category__name=category) |
                       Q(secondary_categories__name=category)).distinct()
    return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        "categories": Category.objects.values("name")
    })
    return context

**ProductDetailView:**

class ProductDetailView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'cart/product_detail.html'
    form_class = AddToCartForm

def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(Product, slug=self.kwargs["slug"])

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("cart:summary")

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs["product_id"] = self.get_object().id
    return kwargs

def form_valid(self, form):
    order = get_or_set_order_session(self.request)
    product = self.get_object()

    item_filter = order.items.filter(
        product=product,
        colour=form.cleaned_data['colour'],
        size=form.cleaned_data['size'],
    )

    if item_filter.exists():
        item = item_filter.first()
        item.quantity += int(form.cleaned_data['quantity'])
        item.save()

    else:
        new_item = form.save(commit=False)
        new_item.product = product
        new_item.order = order
        new_item.save()

    return super(ProductDetailView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product'] = self.get_object()
    return context
```

I have tried the below code which work fine on my product_list but don't work on my
product_detail page

I added get_context_data in to my view and this html, but it doesn't work.

```
**view.py**

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product'] = Product.objects.all()
    return context

**product_detail page**

        {% for product in object_list %}
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
            <div class="product">
              <figure class="product-image">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <img src="{{ product.featured.url }}" alt="Image">
                </a>
              </figure>         
              <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <p class="mb-0">{{ product.title }}</p>
            
              <div class="product-rating mb-0" id="product-rating">
                <i class="icon-star{% if product.avaregereview < 1%}-o empty{% endif%}"></i>
                <i class="icon-star{% if product.avaregereview < 2%}-o empty{% endif%}"></i>
                <i class="icon-star{% if product.avaregereview < 3%}-o empty{% endif%}"></i>
                <i class="icon-star{% if product.avaregereview < 4%}-o empty{% endif%}"></i>
                <i class="icon-star{% if product.avaregereview < 5%}-o empty{% endif%}"></i>
              </div>

              <span class="text-muted text-center">${{ product.get_price }}
                <span class="">/</span>
                <span class="text-danger">{% trans "Add to Cart" %}</span>
              </span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You arent using DetailView, you are using FormView, and you have to indent the code.

Comment: Any error on terminal ?

Comment: def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product'] = Product.objects.all()
    return context             when i apply this it removes everything from  detail page.

Comment: code are well indent in vs code, just from copying and paste here it is disturbing for proper indentation